# How / can I display a console window in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is it possible to have a console window / command-line interface as part of the Intellij IDEA UI?  I'd rather go command-line for certain actions, like working with GIT or kicking off build-processes, but at the moment that means keeping a separate console window open and alt-tabbing.

Is there some form of integrated console?  And even better than that, can it automatically point at my project root by default?

Comment: What you're asking for is called **Terminal** in IntelliJ (Alt+F12). There's also a **Console** window that shows when you run/debug your application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Console/Terminal feature was implemented in IDEA 13, PyCharm 3, RubyMine 6, WebStorm/PhpStorm 7.

There is a [related feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-5166), please vote. Setting up an [external tool](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-third-party-tools.html) to run a terminal can be used as a workaround.

Comment: Disappointing that it's still only at the feature request stage, but at least I know I'm not missing something obvious in the interface.

Vote added to the feature request!

Comment: IntelliJ 13 adds this feature

Answer (score 75):

**IntelliJ IDEA 14 & 15 & 2017**:

View > Tool Windows > Terminal

or

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>

[image]
[image]

Comment: It did not show up in the "Tool Windows" list for me. It was "OFF" in plugins. To switch it on go to Settings --> Plugins --> Search for terminal and switch it on. You can directly access by pressing "Shift" key twice and typing "terminal" in it. See @gotomanners answer below. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28044786/689625

Comment: Haaaaaaaaaaa ha ha ha. 2 years later my own comment saves me again :)

Answer (score 29):

In IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1:

1. View->Tool Windows->Debug (Alt+5)
2. on top right of Debug Window, click "Restore Console View" which is only show a icon like below:

[image: Restore Console View]

Answer (score 17):

More IntelliJ 13+ Shortcuts for Terminal

**Mac OS X**:

<kbd>alt ⌥</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd>

<kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd><kbd>shift ⇧</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> then type `Terminal` then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

<kbd>shift ⇧</kbd><kbd>shift ⇧</kbd><kbd>shift ⇧</kbd><kbd>shift ⇧</kbd> then type `Terminal` then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

**Windows**:

<kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd> press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift ⇧</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> start typing `Terminal` then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

<kbd>shift ⇧</kbd><kbd>shift ⇧</kbd> then type `Terminal` then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 8):

View>Tool Windows>Run

It will show you the console

Comment: Run is not like the normal console

Comment: @AmrAbdulazizIbrahim .No it is not window console.It menu option dropdown in Intellij tool

Comment: Thanks,I need the anwser,because I neet the output when my web app is deploying.

Comment: thanks a lot! I cannot believe I close that one and not sure where to see the logs!

Answer (score 4):

Hover to the sidebar and select the "Restore visual elements of debugger..."

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. Press the left corner button
2. Choose debug
3. Click console

[image]

[image]

Comment: wtf is the left corner button?

Comment: @JohnRPerry It's the **bottom left** corner icon.

Answer (score 1):

I use **Shift + F12** to show the Console again (or **Window > Restore Default Layout**).

To enable that, I have previously saved the layout WITH the console open as default (**Window > Store Current Layout as Default**).

Answer (score 1):

**IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.6**

Using macOS Mojave Version 10.14.4 and pressing <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd>(Alt+F12) will open Sound preferences.

A solution without changing the current keymap is to use the command above with the key <kbd>fn</kbd>.

<kbd>fn</kbd> <kbd>⌥</kbd> <kbd>F12</kbd>(fn+Alt+F12) will open the Terminal. And you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> to close it.

Answer (score -1):

**On IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.1**

Click on the tab that you want to open as window mode.

Right-click on the tab name and select View mode > Window

[image: As this image]