# How to print a java variable when I check through Swagger-UI

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-editor

I am testing an API by Swagger-UI and I need to debug a java variable(query string). I am new to Java and swagger.
I wrote `System.out.print(variable_name)` in the file. But I don't know where it will print the value. I checked in console of swagger. But I could not find the value.
Please help me

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 scenarios :

**Running in Local Machine**

- If you are running the application locally on spring tool suite and
  using swagger ui to check the working of APIs, then you can see the
  console  in the spring tool suite where the application is running .

**Running on Server Machine**

- In this case, you have to see on which server your application is hosted. But ensure that your updated file ( containing the print statement) is present on the server

Comment: But I am running locally using Intellij application.

Comment: so to open the console, you can refer to this article 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768738/how-can-i-display-a-console-window-in-intellij-idea

Comment: @Kavyam does it help ?